# Bad Access when using isEqualToString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk, uiwebview

Ok this is annoying me. I have the following code:

```
weatherAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com"];
    weatherUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherAddress];
    weatherContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:weatherUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

if ([viewer.request.URL.relativeString isEqualToString:weatherContents]) {
   //do stuff
}
```

but when it runs, it sometimes throws a bad access. When i say sometimes I mean usually 50% of the time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `viewer.request.URL.relativeString`? Has it been deallocated? What does the debugger show you when it stops on the exception?

Comment: There's an error in the first line of your posted code. `@"http://google.com` is missing the closing double quote. Did you actually copy/paste this code from your project, or did you retype it?

Comment: try passing `NSError *error` instead of `nil` and see if an error is returned

Comment: Are you sure weatherContents is not nil? Try adding an extra check before the if-statement that ensures it's not nil.

Comment: Definitely not nil. viewer.request...etc gives the current url always. Oh and yes that was just a typo up on top

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you are racing your internet connection.  If you catch the `if` statement before the data is pulled then you have the problem, if your `if` statement loses the race and comes in after the data, then you don't have a problem.  Do an `NSLog` on `weatherContents` and I bet it will be null the times that you crash.

Comment: Maybe tell the program to wait for a sec

Comment: did you determine that that is in fact the problem?  Is `weatherContents` coming up null?

Comment: Waiting is the worst you can do, then you will keep crashing on slow internet connections and wait too long of fast connections. Use asynchronous calls to fetch the data and wait until the data is available before you use `viewer.request.URL.relativeString`.

Comment: `NSURLConnection` has a method named `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` that will allow you do perform URL fetching asynchronous.

Comment: Always check the result of weatherContents first, because it could sometimes be nil, and if so, you'll get a bad access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this, assuming weatherContents is defined in the class:

```
weatherAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com"];
weatherUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:weatherAddress];
weatherContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:weatherUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(checkIfWeatherReceived) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

then create a method called `checkIfWeatherReceived` like so:

```
-(void) checkIfWeatherReceived
{
    if(weatherContents)
    {
        if ([viewer.request.URL.relativeString isEqualToString:weatherContents]) {
            //do stuff
        }
    } else {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(checkIfWeatherReceived) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

I really don't like using stuff that will lock up your interface if your connection drops out, so I would refrain from just "making it wait" or something.  This will check every half a second if the weather data has been grabbed.  If you want it to check faster just change the TimeInterval.  You may want it to be really really fast like .01 or something if you are not finding very much delay in the data.  You should also think about what will happen if the connection is lost and you never get the data, unless you have already accounted for that.  I have not tested this, but I think it should work out, assuming all of your pieces are part of the class and not local to a method.  I would also probably break out the actual work from `checkIfWeatherReceived` into another method, instead of just placing it in the `if(weatherContents)` true area.